# Foil in a Summation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I have the following summation, where I find the following result

$  \sum_{i}^n {(a+b_i)(c+d_i)}   $

$  \sum_{i}^n {(ac+ad_i + bc_i + b_id_i)}  $

However others have told me that I am missing a "N" term in front of the "ac", and I can not see how. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because you are adding n of them together.

Comment: Your multiplication is sound.  What you can do though is say $\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n} (ac + ad_i + bc_i + b_id_i) = \sum_\limits{i=1}^{n} ac + \sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}  (ad_i + bc_i + b_id_i ) = nac + \sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}  (ad_i + bc_i + b_id_i )$

Comment: Hah! Beat me to it.

Comment: ahh got it. Thank you!